# Select mean of the values column wise

Tags: pandas, data-science, data-analysis

I have a dataset in which I have 5 columns. Consider the below database:-

| City | Vehicle | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jaipur | Car | ... | ... | ... |
| Jaipur | Car | ... | ... | ... |
| Jaipur | Bike | ... | ... | ... |
| Pune | Car | ... | ... | ... |
| Mumbai | Bike | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

there are approx 10000 records in which city have 5 value possible that is Jaipur, Pune, Mumbai, Chennai, Indore and Vehicle can have 3 value possible car, bike, Activa.

I used the pandas' group by function over the data frame

```
    df.groupby(['City', 'Vehicle'])['col3'].count()
```

It gave me something as follow:-

| City | Vehicle | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jaipur | Car | 50 |
| Jaipur | Bike | 40 |
| Jaipur | Activa | 60 |
| Pune | Car | 80 |
| Pune | Bike | 90 |
| Pune | Activa | 30 |

But I want ans as below:-

| City | Vehicle | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jaipur | Car | 0.33 |
| Jaipur | Bike | 0.27 |
| Jaipur | Activa | 0.4 |
| Pune | Car | 0.40 |
| Pune | Bike | 0.45 |
| Pune | Activa | 0.15 |

I am not able to understand how to code this in pandas.

Comment: Use `value_counts(normalize=True)` instead of `count()` ?

Comment: To be presice: `df.groupby(['City'])['Vehicle'].value_counts(normalize=True)`.

Comment: Or maybe `df.groupby(['City'])['col3'].value_counts(normalize=True)` if want to count on col3 (but still grouped under City).   As the question title mentions **column-wise**.  Thus, maybe to count for each column for its individual values.   OP need to clarify on this.

Comment: @SeaBean Thanks it worked, it is giving me the answer as I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following if you are to count on `col3` (but still grouped under `City`):

```
df.groupby('City')['col3'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

This will give you the desired relative portions (sum up to 1) instead of the real counts. You can repeat similarly for other columns as well.